# Prove that $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$ if $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than $1$, and $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $n$.

How can I prove that $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ By hypothesis, the prime factors of $\,n\,$ are $\,\color{#c00}{\ge p}.\,$ But the prime factors of $\,p\!-\!1\,$ are $\,\color{#c00}{< p}.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=\gcd(n,p-1)$ then $k$ divides $n$ and assume that $k>1$ so by the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) any prime $p'$ that divides $k$ is a prime that divides $n$ which is impossible since $p'\le k<p$ and $p$ is the smallest prime divides $n$ so $k=1$.

Comment: What would we do without the FTA! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- Let $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_i$ be the prime factors of $n$
- Let $y_1<y_2<\dots<y_j$ be the prime factors of $p-1$
- We know that $y_j \leq p-1 < p = x_1$
- Therefore $y_1<y_2<\dots<y_j<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_i$
- Therefore $n$ and $p-1$ have no common prime factors
- Therefore $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\gcd(n,p-1)\neq 1$. Consider $q$ a prime divisor of $\gcd(n,p-1)$.

$q|\gcd(n,p-1)|n$ and as $q$ is prime, $q\ge p$. But as $q|\gcd(n,p-1)|p-1$, $q<p$. This is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If p is the smallest prime that divides n, then there is no smaller number that divides n: proof - assume so and let q < p divide n, then by definition q is not prime, so q has prime factors which are less than q (and therefore less than p) and since q divides n then these prime factors divide n - contradiction.

If q divides p - 1, then q < p and therefore q cannot divide n, so GCD (n, p-1) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest *prime* divisor is also the smallest non-trivial divisor. Hence $p-1$ does not divide $n$ unless $p-1=1$. In either case, this means that $\gcd (n,p-1)=1$.